# Rails table association with ENUM column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the table `uploads` which holds the relation between 4 different apps and users:

```
field    type
dogTag   int (foreign key to dvd)
app      enum
uploader int (foreign key to user)
mod      string
...
```

And the table `dvds`:

```
dogTag  int (primary key)
title   string
...
```

And the table `users`:

```
id    int (primary key)
...
```

How can I properly construct a model relations between the `dvds` table and the `uploads` table within Rails if it depends on an ENUM column?

With sql I simply do:

```
JOIN uploads ON uploads.dogTag = dvds.dogTag
WHERE uploads.app = 'dvd'
```

But have no idea how to create this relationship in Rails and haven't found a lot of info on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much idea on how to create relation with enum column,but if it's a four model in your app that has one upload model then you can use `polymorphic association`,ryan has great [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could re-organise your db to make the enum type a look up table, you could create a non-persistent model to implement it.

Thing is if you had started from the model instead of the database, you wouldn't have gone anywhere near mysql's enum type, and that's why you are struggling to find much, you've gone at it bass ackwards.

My advice get rid of it...

Comment: Yes, you are quite correct. But it seemed like a good solution at the time when things were a lot simpler :) I'll have to see about getting rid of it, the problem is that there is a bunch of PHP code that relies on that model *sigh*

Comment: Never liked them myself, too many problems for waaaay too few benefits.